# VKApi загрузка документа на сервер

Tags: android, vkontakte-api

Хочу загрузить документ на сервер VK. Прочитал офф. документацию. По ней это делается в несколько этапов. Для начала мы через запрос получаем адрес сервера для загрузки нашего файла. Я получил адрес. Далее мы должны отправить POST-запрос (с multipart data) с этим файлом и после этого завершить сохранение этого файла с помощью метода VkApi.docs().save(). Я не знаю,  как отправить Post-запрос. Пробовал различные способы (с помощью библиотек okhttp и пр.) - не выходит. Может,  у кого есть рабочий пример?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз никто не ответил, - напишу решение, которое нашел. На вход в описанный метод идет файл, который нужно загрузить в ВК.

```
public void SendDocToServer(File file){
    VKApiDocs docs = new VKApiDocs();
    VKRequest request = docs.uploadDocRequest(file);
    request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener(){
        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response){
            super.onComplete(response);
            //Файл загружен успешно 
        }
    });
}
```